# Using an enum as a constant expression. Which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code uses enum member `m` as a constant expression, i.e. as a template parameter. The code compiles under gcc but not under clang ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79f0d052864fec19%20live%20demo)). Clang says "error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression".

The problem can be solved by exchanging line `// 1` by `A<tst<p>::m> a`. Therefore, my question is not how to fix this issue but which compiler is right.

```
template<size_t n> struct A{};

template<size_t n>
struct tst
{   enum : size_t { m= n % 15 };

    template<size_t p>
    void
    call( tst<p> const &t2 ) {
        A<t2.m>  a; // 1
    }
};
```

Comment: [This references says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) "When an unscoped enumeration is a class member, its enumerators may be accessed using class member access operators `.` and `->`". It doesn't mention anything about being constant expressions though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The standard `§ 7.2.2` does say `The identifiers in an
enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are required.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Standard, Clang is right to reject the code.

`t2.m` is a class member access expression. [expr.ref]/1 says:

> [...] The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated; the
>   result of that evaluation, together with the *id-expression*,
>   determines the result of the entire postfix expression.

There's also a note:

> If the class member access expression is evaluated, the subexpression
>   evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary to determine the
>   value of the entire postfix expression, for example if the
>   *id-expression* denotes a static member.

So, the subexpression `t2` is evaluated. [expr.const]/2.9 says that an expression `e` cannot be a core constant expression if evaluating it results in the evaluation of

> an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference
>   type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
> - it is initialized with a constant expression or
> - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

`t2` refers to a variable of reference type that doesn't satisfy the bullets, so `t2.m` is not a constant expression because it isn't a core constant expression.

---

All quotes from N4594, the current published working draft. The text has changed slightly since C++11, but the meaning in this case is the same.

Comment: Thx. Did anybody file a bug report for gcc?

Comment: @ClaasBontus I haven't. A search through the bug database would be in order, but I didn't get the time to do that so far.

Comment: Possibly [Bug 39970](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39970).

Comment: @ClaasBontus Related, but your example is not a strict duplicate, I think. Using the names in that example, if we try to instantiate either `template_blah<>` (which will use the default template argument) or `template_blah<global.member>`, GCC will correctly diagnose the error (even for `struct blah`, avoiding the access control error).