# Static member access in constant expressions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr, static-members

Accessing static class member functions or variables, can be done in two ways: through an object (`obj.member_fun()` or `obj.member_var`) or through the class (`Class::member_fun()` or `Class::member_var`). However, in `constexpr` functions, Clang gives an error on the object access and requires to use class access:

```
struct S 
{
    constexpr static auto s_v = 42;    
    constexpr static auto v() { return s_v; }
};

#define TEST 1

constexpr auto foo(S const& s [[maybe_unused]]) 
{
#if TEST
    constexpr auto v = s.v();   // ERROR for clang, OK for gcc
#else    
    constexpr auto v = S::v();  // OK for clang and gcc
#endif
    return v;
}

constexpr auto bar(S const& s [[maybe_unused]])
{
#if TEST   
    constexpr auto v = s.s_v;   // ERROR for clang, OK for gcc
#else    
    constexpr auto v = S::s_v;  // OK for clang and gcc
#endif    
    return v;
}

int main() {}
```

[**Live Example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j3JdM0WEOSHsK0R3) compiled with `-std=c++1z` and `#define TEST 1` for Clang 5.0 SVN, with error message:

> ```
> Start
> prog.cc:12:24: error: constexpr variable 'v' must be initialized by a constant expression
>     constexpr auto v = s.v();   // ERROR for clang, OK for gcc
>                        ^~~~~
> prog.cc:22:24: error: constexpr variable 'v' must be initialized by a constant expression
>     constexpr auto v = s.s_v;   // ERROR for clang, OK for gcc
>                        ^~~~~
> 2 errors generated.
> 1
> Finish
> ```

**Question**: is this is a Clang bug, or is gcc too liberal in accepting both syntax forms for static member access in a `constexpr` function?

Comment: did the compiled code by gcc work

Comment: @VIPER yes it did (although this is a reduced example)

Comment: In practice, you should not do that anyway even if it was allowed...

Comment: Seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38398475/3876684).

Comment: That `foo` and `bar` are `constexpr` functions is irrelevant. See [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dpo1l30pwb2xeHhF).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Clang seems to be in the right. When accessing a static member with the member access syntax [[class.static/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.static#1):

> A static member s of class X may be referred to using the qualified-id
>   expression X​::​s; it is not necessary to use the class member access
>   syntax to refer to a static member. **A static member may be referred to
>   using the class member access syntax, in which case the object
>   expression is evaluated.**

So `s.v()` will cause `s` to be evaluated. Now, according to [[expr.const/2.11]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11), `s` is not a constant expression:

> 2 An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation
>   of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one
>   of the following expressions:
>
> [...]
>
> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference
>   type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either:
>   (2.11.1) - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   (2.11.2) - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

`s` doesn't have a preceding initialization with a constant expression, not in the scope of `foo`.

---

If you want to access the static members based of a function parameter, without hard-coding the type, the way forward is `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>`. This is accepted by Clang and GCC both:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S 
{
    constexpr static auto s_v = 42;    
    constexpr static auto v() { return s_v; }
};

constexpr auto foo(S const& s) 
{
    constexpr auto v = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>::v();
    return v;
}

constexpr auto bar(S const& s)
{
    constexpr auto v = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>::s_v;
    return v;
}

int main() {}
```

Comment: I also remember hearing something like "parameters are not `constexpr`, but you can get around that by wrapping the value in a lambda". (though I can't get it to work right now: https://godbolt.org/g/V8tzMG)

Comment: @JornVernee - I don't see how the lambda helps here. Perhaps you could fiddle with your example to demonstrate?

Comment: I think the idea is that a `constexpr` lambda can return a `constexpr` value, which can then be used to initialize a `constexpr` variable. I can initialize `s` in `main` with that lambda, but for some reason it doesn't work when initializing `r` when passed to the functions.

Comment: If GCC is in the wrong here, it would be great if someone would file a bug with them.

Comment: @ClaasBontus That trick also works for the original, you can remove `constexpr` from `v` to make it compile. I guess `constexpr` only looks at the initializing expression, and not at the resulting value of that expression.

Comment: @underscore_d this has been reported in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79083 (among other similar ones, see the "see also" section). Unfortunately there does not seem to be much activity on any of these.

Answer (score -1):

```
constexpr auto v = s.v();   // ERROR for clang, OK for gcc
```

I guess it depends on whether you compile in C++11 or C++14 mode. If you look over at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression), you will find (emphasis added by me):

> A core constant expression is any expression that **does not have any one of the following**
>   (...)
>   6) The `this` pointer, except if used for class member access inside a non-static member function (until C++14)
>   6) The `this` pointer, **except in a constexpr function** or a constexpr constructor that is being **evaluated as part of the expression** (since C++14)

So, in C++11, whatever happens inside `s.v()` would not be considered a constant expression, since it uses the `this` pointer, but it is **not** a non-static member function (it's `static`) accessing a class member.

Per C++14, however, it would be, since it is evaluating a `constexpr` function as part of the expression, so the "except if" clause on the "does not have any of" set of rules catches.

Now don't ask me whether that makes any sense or whether anyone is supposed to understand that... :-)

Comment: Updated the question with c++1z tag