# Accessing a static constexpr member from a member variable, GCC bug?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, compiler-bug

The following compiles without error:

```
template<int j, int i>
struct TemplateClass { 
    int arr[i];
};
struct A {
    inline static constexpr int n = 123; 
};
template<int j> struct B {
    void func() {
        A a;
        TemplateClass<j, a.n> c;
    }
};
int main() {
  B<456> b;
  b.func();
}
```

However, **compiling with GCC**, we get the error *"use of 'this' in a constant expression"* if we make a member variable of the variable `A a` in the function `func`, like this:

```
template<int j> struct B {
    A a;
    void func() {
        TemplateClass<j, a.n> c;
    }
};
```

**Compiling with MSVC** gives no error. [Compare the two compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/_vgsfd),

- I do not understand why this gives an error. Is this a bug?
- Is there a workaround to circumvent this error?

Comment: IIRC this was asked last week.  I'll try and find it.  I believe it is the subject of a defect report.

Comment: Is the workaround to just use `A::n`?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, yes that works! `decltype(a)::n` also works.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995196/static-member-access-in-constant-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is correct. A template argument must be a constant expression, and `a.n` implicitly means `this->a.n` since `a` is a member of the enclosing class. But a constant expression evaluation cannot access `this` inside a non-`constexpr` member function ([expr.const]/2.1). And even though evaluating `this` appears unnecessary in order to obtain the value of the static member `n`, the standard requires that `a` (which means `this->a`) be evaluated even though its value is not needed; see [expr.ref]/1 and its footnote.

GCC will accept your code if `func` is marked `constexpr`. As pointed out in the comments, it's better to just write `A::n`, though.

Comment: So its an MSVC non compliance ... Not what I expected.