# Clang report "constexpr if condition is not a constant expression" while GCC is ok

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, language-lawyer, clang++

I'm using clang 9.0.1 and gcc 9.2.1 on x64 Linux, both with `--std=c++17` (or `--std=c++2a`).

Gcc can build the following example without any error or warning, while clang++ reports `error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression` on both `if constexpr` lines. (btw, on my MacBook, Apple clang-11.0.0 reports the same error too.)

MCVE:

```
#include <utility>

enum class TopicType {
    MarketData = 'M',
    Timer = 'T',
};

template<class Topic>
struct TopicBase {
    constexpr static TopicType type() { return Topic::type; };
    const Topic& topicImp;
    explicit TopicBase(const Topic &t) : topicImp(t) {}
};

struct MarketDataTopic {
    static constexpr TopicType type{TopicType::MarketData};
};

struct TimerTopic {
    static constexpr TopicType type{TopicType::Timer};
};

template<class Topic>
int subscribe(TopicBase<Topic>&& topic) {

    if constexpr (topic.type() == TopicType::MarketData) { // <-- clang++ reports error here
        return 1;
    }
    if constexpr (topic.type() == TopicType::Timer) { // and error here
        return 2;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    MarketDataTopic m{};
    TimerTopic t{};

    TopicBase<MarketDataTopic> b1{m};
    TopicBase<TimerTopic> b2{t};

    subscribe(std::move(b1));


    return 0;
}
```

Online compiler https://godbolt.org/z/rARi_N has the same result.

So which compiler is right about this? And if it is an error, how to fix it for clang?

Comment: [Simplified example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37965955e2644a84). The lvalue/rvalue reference is the issue.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It seems it is related with it, here is the modified working OP's code. https://godbolt.org/z/2HiLGe which takes valueby

Comment: @arnes Yes pass by value is OK. But I need to pass it by reference, the struct may be complicated.

Comment: @halfelf I didn't suggest you to pass by value, I just wanted to state that the behaviour of clang may not be a bug and probably has meaningful explanation which I dont know :(

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do this to make it work for clang:

```
template<class Topic>
int subscribe(TopicBase<Topic>&& topic) {
    using myType = TopicBase<Topic>;
    if constexpr (myType::type() == TopicType::MarketData) { // <-- clang++ reports error here
        return 1;
    }
    if constexpr (myType::type() == TopicType::Timer) { // and error here
        return 2;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[Run live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LLaRWeADed0XBT6l)

Most probably that's a bug in clang. Better report it.

Comment: Actually, It seems it is related with rvalue reference, it works when we take the object valueby `TopicBase<Topic> topic` but i don't know why.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted.  I'm not very familiar with if constexpr condition before, is there some explanation in standard about this strange behavior?

Comment: @halfelf maybe you need a 'language-lawyer' tag at question.

Comment: @arnes So it turns out clang is correct(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995196/static-member-access-in-constant-expressions). Bless the cpp gods.