# When does reference evaluation make something not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr

Consider the [following snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lghzIHNDM3gt2JOH):

```
struct test1 {
    static constexpr int get()  {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct test2 {
    constexpr int get() const {
        return 1;
    }
};

template <class T>
int get(T&& t) {
    if constexpr (t.get() == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    return get(test1{}) + get(test2{});
}
```

When trying to compile with GCC-11.1 (-std=c++2a), `get` template successfully compiles with `test1`, but not with `test2`. The only difference between them is fact that `test2::get` is static.

Obviously, it does not compile with `test2`, because `t` parameter is not a "core constant expression", as per [7.7 expr.const(5.13)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.13):

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of
> e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of
> the following expressions:
>
> - an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of **reference type** unless the reference has a **preceding initialization**...

The question is why it does compile, when the function being accessed via the very same reference is static. Isn't the refence "evaluated" in this case?  Is it a GCC bug or there's some wording in the Standard that allows it?

Comment: Clang doesn't accept `get(test1)`

Comment: A dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44995196/817643 I reckon

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica cool, thanks!  So it's a bug in GCC.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica This has been flagged as future DR for C++11 through C++20 via [P2280R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2280r3.html), [aimed for C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/973).

Comment: @dfrib - There's a big difference between being flagged and going through. Be careful your answer doesn't make empty promises.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Given that [EWG has consensus about the issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/973#issuecomment-938851420) and will send it forward to CWG, it can be argued to be a quite a likely future DR.

Comment: @dfrib - I recall a fair few things falling through at the last moment. So again, big difference.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I agree, particularly when it comes to many proposed new core language and library features, but is this also the case for defect topics that has already been under the purview (and approval/go-forward) of EWG? CWG assistant chair Jens M. has just recently tagged this particular topic for the 2022 teleconf.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I was clearly wrong ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pointers and references to unknowns in constant expressions being directly ill-formed *will possibly* be addressed in C++23 and, if so, as a Defect Report for earlier language versions.**

---

> [...] when the function being accessed via the very same reference is static. Isn't the refence "evaluated" in this case? Is it a GCC bug or there's some wording in the Standard that allows it?

Your program is ill-formed also for the `static` case, as is answered in detail in the follow Q&A:

- [Static member access in constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995196/static-member-access-in-constant-expressions)

However, EWG considered this a defect in the specification of constexpr, and recommending CWG to consider resolving it by [P2280R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2280r3.html) (*Using unknown pointers and references in constant expressions*), targeted for C++23, and as a DR (defect report) for C++11 through C++20.

> **jfbastien commented on Feb 3, 2021**
>
> EWG saw this paper in today's telecon.
>
> P2280 Using unknown references in constant expressions
>
> The use cases presented in P2280 are problems in C++’s specification of constexpr, and we would like to fix these problems, ideally in C++23.
>
> This should be a Defect Report against C++20, C++17, C++14, and C++11.

CWG agreed and [P2280 has now been accepted into C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/973) and as a defect report.